# 'texture2D' : No matching overloaded function found OpenGL ES2?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, texture2d

I was working on a project, and for that project I  had to walk through a book called "OpenGL ES 2 For Android: A quick start guide".
So when I got to texturing, I got the error of:

```
'texture2D' : No matching overloaded function found
```

...when I compile the shader.

The shader code:

```c
// Fragment shader
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec4 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
}

// Vertex shader
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec4 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
    v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
}
```

I tried the same shaders for my project and for exactly the same code as in the book but it still gives me the same error when I compile the shader, and the viewport on the android device is blank, just the clear color I set is shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
varying vec4 v_TextureCoordinates;
        ^^^^
```

There are exactly two `texture2D()` overloads in ES 2.0:

```
vec4 texture2D(sampler2D sampler, vec2 coord)
vec4 texture2D(sampler2D sampler, vec2 coord, float bias)
```

...neither of which accept a `vec4` for `coord`.

Slice off the last two vector components of `v_TextureCoordinates` using a swizzle:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates.xy );
```